# Earth Engine client library loading failed Failed to initialize with API at https://earthengine.googleapis.com. Invalid JSON:

Tags: google-earth-engine

Unfortunately, when I open GEE I come up with this error:

```
Earth Engine client library loading failed
Failed to initialize with API at https://earthengine.googleapis.com.
 Invalid JSON:
```

Then, I continue to GEE, files of my projects cannot be shown:

```
/**** Start of imports. If edited, may not auto-convert in the playground. ****/
var modis_lulc = ee.ImageCollection("MODIS/006/MCD12Q1"),
    table = ee.FeatureCollection("projects/ee-hirsa/assets/Aliabad"),
    landsat = ee.ImageCollection("LANDSAT/LE07/C02/T1_L2");
/***** End of imports. If edited, may not auto-convert in the playground. *****/
```

How can I fix this error?

Comment: Have you tried refreshing the page?

Comment: ya, I have done but no results